# How can I request camera permission in Android Studio new version

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera

[image]

I want to get camera permission in Android, but when I used this code, it didn't work. It shows me an error. Can you please help me solve this problem or you can show the code I can use to get this permission?

```java
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 0);
```

For better understanding, please see the image. I am using Gradle version 7.2, and plugin 7.1.3.

I already tried, but I failed, please suggest me the code I need to use.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: thanks, i attaced an image, please see this

Comment: import android.Manifest;

Comment: hello, i already added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> , but it still showed error

Comment: hi, thanks, it works finaly, i just change the version code of app:compact then its works fine.

Comment: if the issue is fixed then closed it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this import statement.

```
import android.Manifest
```